# dynamic inject custom component into modal

Tags: angular, dynamic, service, modal-dialog, components

I have write a custom `modal` and a `modalService`, which provide two function to open and close modal.

and now , I have another component called `select-list` component, what i want to do is to dynamic inject cascade-select in to the modal `viewContainerRef` ,

what makes me confuse is that how can i get the result when i close the modal via modal's **confirm** `button`

here is my code

`modalComponent.ts`:

```
export class ModalComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {

  isOpened: boolean = false;

  @Output() onCancel: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

  @Output() onConfirm: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter(false);

  // =======================
  // 公共属性
  // =======================

  @ViewChild('modalRoot') modalRoot: ElementRef;

  // =======================
  // 私有属性
  // =======================

  @ViewChild('modalBody', {read: ViewContainerRef}) dynamicTarget: ViewContainerRef;

  constructor() {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.modalService.registerModal(this);
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
  }
}
```

`modalComponent.html`:

```
<!-- 弹层 S -->
<div class="modal-mask" [ngStyle]="{display: isOpened ? 'block': 'none'}"></div>
<div class="modal" role="popup-dialog" #modalRoot [ngStyle]="{display: isOpened ? 'block': 'none'}">
  <div [class]="'modal-dialog ' + clazz" #modalDialog (click)="preventClosing($event)">
    <div class="modal-content" tabindex="0">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <ng-content select="[modal-header]"></ng-content>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <span #modalBody></span>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button *ngIf="cancelButtonLabel.length > 0" (click)="cancel()" class="button cancel" #cancelButton [class.full-fill]="
      !confirmButtonLabel">{{cancelButtonLabel}}</button>
        <button *ngIf="confirmButtonLabel.length > 0" (click)="confirm()" class="button primary" #confirmButton [class.full-fill]="!cancelButtonLabel">{{confirmButtonLabel}}</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- 弹层 E -->
```

`modalService.ts`:

```
@Injectable()
export class ModalService {

  // 弹层实例对象
  private modal: ModalComponent;
  private componentRef: ComponentRef<Component>;
  private viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef;

  constructor(private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver) { }

  registerModal(newModal: ModalComponent): void {
    this.modal = newModal;
  }

  // create<T>(module: any, component: any, params?: Object): Observable<ComponentRef<T>> {
  //   let componentRef$ = new ReplaySubject();
  // }

  open(component, opt?: Object): ModalComponent {
    if (this.componentRef) {
      this.componentRef.destroy();
    }
    // 动态加载其它组件
    let factory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(component);
    this.componentRef = this.modal.dynamicTarget.createComponent(factory);
    this.modal.isOpened = true;
    return this.modal;
  }

  close(): void {
    this.modal.isOpened = false;
  }
}
```

then, i do this to in my `appComponent.ts`:

```
this.modalService.open(SelectListComponent);
```

`appComponent.html`:

```
<mcare-modal #mcareModal
title="自定义弹窗"
cancelButtonLabel="取消"
confirmButtonLabel="确定"
(onConfirm)="actionOnConfirm($event)"
[modalId]="modalId">
<div modal-header>
  <div class="row-control">
    <h4 class="title">{{modalTitle}}</h4>
  </div>
</div>
```

the thumbnail

[modal show image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J72pd.png)